# need help returning sql sum of $variable table name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables, sum

I'm trying to return the sum of balances from a table and can get the following code to work when using a specific table name

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Balance) AS total FROM table1 ");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
echo $row['total'];
```

The problem I'm having is that my table name changes and this needs to be a variable but when I use the following code I get no result

```
$table="table1";
$qry = mysql_query(" SELECT SUM(Balance) AS total FROM $table ");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
echo $row['total'];
```

Can anyone offer some help please?

Comment: You have to use dynamic query/prepared statement. You can't use table name or column name as variable.

Comment: @Rahul, Since he's using the old deprecated `mysql_` functions without prepared statements he can use variables for the table name.

Comment: There are more differences than you're letting on. For instance, where'd the extra space at the beginning of the query come from?  Probably more differences higher up where it connects to the db too.

Comment: @developerwjk, I have no idea about PHP. That comment is solely based on MySQL.

Comment: @developerwjk you can use variables to build your query in any other driver as well. talking about regular PHP variables, not prepared inserts.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. The extra space is just a typo and I have tried changing only the table name.  Would it be better to change the way I'm doing this? or can it be done with a variable table name?

Comment: @Andyish There's nothing wrong with your code.. if there's an error it's not here.

Comment: @Adelphia  Thanks, I'm not sure why it doesnt work then. I when I run the page with the table name typed it echos the total balance but when using the variable it doesn't. The rest of the page is exactly the same.

Comment: @Andyish did you copy the above code directly off the page?

Comment: Sorry to waste everyones time, it was a different part of the page that was causing the error using the same variable name twice.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$qry = mysql_query(" SELECT SUM(Balance) AS total FROM " .  $table  );
```